# Multiple columns joined to a single column SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables that are related each other, Table1 and Table2.

Table1:

```
ID int IDENTITY Primary Key
Col1 varchar(15)
```

Table2:

```
ID int IDENTITY Primary Key
CenterID int
SatelliteID int
Category varchar(15)
```

`Table2.CenterID` and `Table2.SatelliteID` are referencing `Table1.ID` (foreign key).

The question is, I want to retrieve the data of `Table1` with criteria of `Table2.CenterID`, `Table2.SatelliteID`, and `Table2.Category`.

How should I join 2 columns that are referencing the same key?

Here is my code

```
SELECT ta1.* FROM Table1 ta1
INNER JOIN Table2 ta2a ON ta2a.CenterID = ta1.ID
INNER JOIN Table2 ta2b ON ta2b.SatelliteID = ta1.ID
WHERE ....
```

Comment: what you have done so far?

Comment: well, I "inner joined" the 2 foreign key columns using aliasing, and then supply the search criteria using where clause (all of criterias that I mentioned above, using AND operator), the result is nothing retrieved

Comment: your question would be vastly improved if there was sample data and the expected result, words alone are too vague

Comment: @wulung_try, provide the same code what you have tried, that will help you get answer faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just join Table2 twice once with CenterID and the second time with SatelliteID:

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2a.*, t2b.* FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2a ON t2a.CenterID = t1.id
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2b ON t2b.SateliteID = t1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like below:

```
select 
    table2.id,
    t1.Col1 as Center, 
    t2.Col1 as Satellite,
    table2.category
from table2 left join 
table1 t1 
on t1.ID= table2.centerid
left join table1 t2
on t1.ID= table2.satelliteid
--- add where criteria here
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make multiple joins with table two

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableB AS b 
INNER JOIN TableA AS a1 ON b.CenterID  = a1.Id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableA AS a2 ON b.SatelliteID = a2.Id
```

Add INNER JOIN or LEFT OUTER JOIN this will be according to you requirement.